# Can I use British English in an Australian conference paper?

Tags: peer-review, conference, language, australia

I have written a peer-reviewed paper for an Australian academic conference. The reviews are favourable with a number of small and helpful suggestions. However, one reviewer has criticised the use of the word "amongst", saying it is archaic and should not therefore be used in a technical paper.

In British English, "amongst" is more commonly used in everyday and technical language, and to my (British) ear, it fits better than the alternative "among" in the context that I have used it. In fact, it was introduced to the language more recently. However, in US English, it is less often used and could be considered archaic. Australian English has many similarities with American English, so it may be considered archaic there too.
My question is whether the paper should be "corrected" to Australian English as it is an Australian conference, or if "correct" UK English should be allowed from a UK writer?

I am not trying to pick a fight, and the acceptance of the paper is not at stake - this is merely a suggestion from the reviewer - but I am interested in what would be considered the correct approach.

Comment: Some reviewers feel the need to point out a few typos or nitpick some grammar to "prove" that they read the paper. I would not take such a comment seriously.

Comment: For sure! They understand also british english.

Comment: What!!! That comment is so odd. We do use amongst and whilst,  no problem. In fact, Australian English is typically British except for tiny variations. We use colour not color, behaviour not behavior, optimisation not optimization.  I don't think you need to take this comment too seriously.

Comment: I suggest that you should not use "strine... A technical paper written in colloquial Australian may not go down too well...

Comment: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=among%2Camongst&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camong%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camongst%3B%2Cc0) disagrees with your claim that "amongst" is more common than "among" in British English: "among" has more than five times the frequency and has always been much more common. "Amongst" just adds two redundant letters but I will fight to the death for your right to use it. Well, not to the death. But your reviewer is being silly.

Comment: @Thomas One could even choose to read it as a subtle compliment: "Your paper was so good that this is the most significant 'problem' I could find."

Comment: I was told once, on choosing the "flavour" of English for papers: if you chose to write your paper in US-English, the US readers will think "Their writing is okay", while the UK readers will think "Oh, I see, they're using US English". If you chose to write in UK-English, on the other hand, the UK readers will think "Their grammar is okay", while the US readers will think "Oh gosh, they can't use English at all!". But, the bottom line is exactly as @None said: pick whichever, and be consistent (just expect more of these types of comments if you don't chose the US-flavour).

Comment: And as an addendum - while UK-English will typically cause more grammar comments from English speakers from other regions, it's on you to decide how much dealing with those bothers you. I've yet to see that stop my British supervisor from using his native English. In fact, now I'm slightly hoping we get one of those comments for some of our next submissions, I'd love to see his reaction to somebody complaining about either his grammar or his style.

Comment: I will note that there are a few words which mean _completely_ different things in different dialects of English, so be sure you're not running afoul of any of those. You're less likely to hit this in technical jargon, but be cautious nonetheless. The most recent example for me is "torch", which means a handheld electric light in BrE, but a stick on fire in AmE.

Comment: FYI: The Macquarie Dictionary is a dictionary of Australian English. It is generally held by universities and the legal profession to be the authoritative source on Australian English. (Wikipedia)

amongst /əˈmʌŋst/

preposition 1.  among.

–phrase 2. get amongst.
a.  (of a wild animal) to move into (a flock, herd, etc.) in search of prey, causing panic: a fox getting amongst the chooks.
b.  to engage in doing, acquiring, consuming, etc., enthusiastically: to get amongst the wickets.

3. get amongst it, to take one's share, with great enthusiasm, of whatever spoils are on offer.

Comment: @penelope "just expect more of these types of comments if you don't chose the US-flavour" *US-flavor  (just kidding, of course. :) )

Comment: Think for a moment how many people write papers in English when it is not their first language, and how they look to you. One word that is seen as slightly archaic makes hardly a ripple, when people have to referee papers the grammar of which is consistently incorrect throughout.

Comment: @reirab I was wondering if somebody will spot it :P

Answer (score 23):

> My question is whether the paper should be "corrected" to Australian
>   English as it is an Australian conference, or if "correct" UK English
>   should be allowed from a UK writer?

British English is acceptable in US-based or other places conferences that do not use British English. Each conference writes their requireements in the Call for Papers. Mostly, international conferences require English. But it is unreasonable to require specific English. Even if it Australian-based conference. Any English is acceptable. Just be consistent in the whole text on the English you choose.

Comment: Not sure how this got so many upvotes. I came looking precisely because the conference I want to submit to (EMNLP) does *not* put that in the CfP. My father published a philosophy book with MIT Press and was forced to change all spelling to US. Definitely not "Any English is acceptable".

Answer (score 15):

> I am not trying to pick a fight, and the acceptance of the paper is not at stake - this is merely a suggestion from the reviewer

I think you (and some of the other answers) are overthinking this. Suggestions from reviewers are precisely that - suggestions. Some are good, some are less good, and you are free to adopt or ignore them at your pleasure. There is  nothing at stake here no matter what you decide. Hence, I feel that the analyses of the relative frequency of usage of “among” vs “amongst” in British English, and other such considerations being brought up, are simply beside the point. This is one occasion where *you can literally do whatever you want*. Feels nice, doesn’t it? ;-)

Comment: ikr, but just look how much academics love to overthink!

Answer (score 2):

Until the 70s in Australia we spoke officially in Received Pronunciation and Received Standard was our official grammar standard. Those days are past. And 95% of Australians did not speak that way.

The most official standard is the Australian Government Style Guide. However most organisations do not follow it. Harvard and Chicago are both more popular.

The second most official is the Macquarie Dictionary. See https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/ (but it's not free).

This is Oxford's Dictionary take on it. https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/02/05/among-amongst/

The practise in Australia is to simplify older longer words with shorter words. Having said that, not everyone agrees.

Comment: I wonder: What is the percentage of English people who do not speak in Received Pronunciation?  I wouldn't be surprised if it is around 95%, and of course the percentage of British people not speaking RP will be higher still. For Australia, 95% is much lower than I would have expected, though I've never been there.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, unless there is a specific rule in the call for papers, any geographic variety of English should be acceptable, particularly if it conforms to the formal usage of a country with large numbers of native speakers (i.e., the U.S., the U.K., Canada, Australia, Ireland, New Zealand, South Africa). When there is such a rule, it is most likely to be confined to matters of spelling and punctuation, leaving aside issues of vocabulary and grammar.

The reviewer in this case is likely to be American, as we Americans, forming the overwhelming majority of native speakers and lacking as strong a cultural connection with the U.K. as the other English-speaking countries have, generally have the lowest awareness of usage in other countries. Even if *amongst* were uncommon in Australia, which it isn't, few Australians would be so unfamiliar with British usage as to comment on it.

It's true that a number of words commonly used in Britain, *amongst* among them, sound somewhat bookish to American ears. That's because we read them but rarely hear them. "Archaic" is a real exaggeration, though.

I think a tactful reviewer reading a mostly well-written paper with a handful of things that sound odd to them should ideally be aware of the possibility that these might be legitimate geographic variants. Realistically, this won't always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the one word `amongst`, change it and move on. I doubt that the strength or validity of your paper hinges on use of that word.

Now, if they said the paper in its entirety is in the *wrong* English it would be best to ask the editor whether the journal/conference agrees. It would take a considerable amount of work to rewrite a paper in an unfamiliar dialect, and the strength of the paper could suffer.

Comment: What if it's the _two_ words, "amongst" and "whilst"? ;-)

Comment: It may take a whilst to convince the reviewers they are wrongst ;) But seriously, the fact that the Oxford Dictionary online dismisses "whilst" with just a two word entry - "British: while" - and "amongst" doesn't even get its own entry at all, merely a variant "British" spelling of "among",  that must be saying something about their contemporary importance.

Comment: @alephzero The Google Ngram I quoted in a comment to the question shows that "amongst" counts for about one sixth of current British use of "among/amongst". That's clearly of "contemporary importance"; it's just that the OED has nothing to say about "amongst" beyond that it's a British variant of "among".

Comment: The reviewer may not be aware that whilst is in contemporary use -- I wasn't myself, until I spent time in the UK recently. I would guess that the reviewer's comment is just ignorance about British English, rather than a rejection of British English.

Comment: Well, regardless of the British dictionaries,  "amongst" still appears in Australian English dictionaries.  See my comment to the OP.

Comment: `I doubt that the strength or validity of your paper hinges on use of that word.` No - as per the original question - in fact, the question is entirely academic (!)

Comment: "British variant" :( BrE is the reference implementation mmkay

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the reference implementation has changed since the other implementations were forked from it.

Comment: @phoog Yes, it has, but it's still the reference implementation :)